# EF - Efficiently Load Self-Referential Hierarchy where each hierarchy element references a single entity

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have a self referential hierarchy in EF with a twist. There's an entity that represents the hierarchy itself. This entity has a one to many relationship with the entries in the hierarchy itself.

Here's the (somewhat elided) classes:

```
[Table("Hierarchies")]
public class Hierarchy
{
    public Hierarchy()
    {
        Entries = new List<HierarchyEntry>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HierarchyEntry> Entries { get; set; }
}

[Table("HierarchyEntries")]
public class HierarchyEntry
{
    public HierarchyEntry()
    {
        Children = new List<HierarchyEntry>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Hierarchy")]
    public int HierarchyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CostCenterHierarchy Hierarchy { get; set; }
    public CostCenterHierarchyEntry Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HierarchyEntry> Children { get; set; }
}
```

From a database point of view, I can obviously get the hierarchy members with a single query. However, as I descend the hierarchy, I can see EF constantly querying the database for the children of that level.

The situation is unusual use case for EF, so I don't mind having to do a bit of work to get the hierarchy happy, but I can't seem to keep it from querying each time I work with children.

Is there a way to instruct EF about this situation so I can stop hammering my database?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I changed the Children property on HierarchyEntry to be a plain old collection (not an EF navigation property). I used a read only collection interface to avoid potential bugs with someone not realizing that this isn't an EF tracked collection.

Since my use case always involves loading the entire hierarchy, I added a method at the hierarchy that would manage the creation of these child collections throughout the hierarchy.

This works well enough for my purposes, but it definitely feels clunky. I'd welcome any other approaches.